# How do I use GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT in OpenGL ES 3.1 on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-extensions

I recently switched from using `glBufferData` to `glMapBufferRange` which gives me direct access to GPU memory rather than copying the data from CPU to GPU every frame.

This works just fine and in OpenGL ES **3.0** I do the following per frame:

- Get a pointer to my GPU buffer memory via `glMapBufferRange`.
- Directly update my buffer using this pointer.
- Use `glUnmapBuffer` to unmap the buffer so that I can render.

But some Android devices may have at least OpenGL ES 3.1 and, as I understand it, may also have the [EXT_buffer_storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_buffer_storage.txt) extension (please correct me if that's the wrong extension ?). Using this extension it's possible to set up **persistent** buffer pointers which do not require mapping/unmapping every frame using the `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` flag. But I can't figure out or find much online in the way of how to access these features.

How exactly do I invoke `glMapBufferRange` with `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` set in OpenGL ES 3.1 on Android ?

Examining [`glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetString.xml) does seem to show the extension is present on my device, but I can't seem to find `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` anwhere, e.g. in `GLES31` or `GLES31Ext`, and I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: "*I can't seem to find GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT anwhere, e.g. in GLES31 or GLES31Ext*" What are you looking in where you cannot find them? Also, they would have the `_EXT` suffix.

Comment: @NicolBolas In Android Studio, e.g., if I type `GLES30.` or `GLES31.` or `GLES31Ext.` the intelli sense does not show up `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` (with or without `EXT` on the end)

Comment: I found this (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES31Ext) and the tokens I would expect to find just aren't there, so as a previous comment mentioned (which has since been deleted) the functionality I require might not actually be available. It was a bit confusing because `glGetString` returns that the extension is supported, but I guess it's just not supported yet by Google's extension API's. So I will stick to my current use of `glMapBufferRange` as described above and hope that Vulkan provides better support when I make the switch later on.

Comment: @Pixel The value of `MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT_EXT` is _0x0040_. If [EXT_buffer_storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_buffer_storage.txt) is supported by your hardware, you can define the value yourself.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think this goes back to my original problem. I can make my own flag for `0x0040` but according to the docs I need to use `glBufferStorage` to allocate my buffer to use that flag instead of `glBufferData`. But I can't seem to find a way to access `glBufferStorage` via the `EXT_buffer_storage` extension. I don't know how to find/use `glBufferStorage` - it doesn't seem accessible in any way from Android.

Comment: As pointed out in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245319/minimal-working-example-of-compute-shader-for-open-gl-es-3-1/51249789?noredirect=1#comment119240771_51249789) (since deleted) it turns out `glBufferStorage` isn't available in OpenGL ES so unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to use `MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` anyway, at least officially. That's really confusing because Android reports `EXT_storage_buffer` as an available extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Android Java bindings for OpenGL ES only expose extensions that are guaranteed to be supported by all implementations on Android. If you want to expose less universally available vendor extensions you'll need to roll your own JNI bindings, using `eglGetProcAddress()` from native code compiled with the NDK to fetch the entry points.

For this one you want the extension entry point `glBufferStorageEXT()`.